# Creating a custom framework which uses RealmSwift

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, realm

When using realm in a simple project, I used the following steps from realm's instructions:

> 1. Download the latest release of Realm and extract the zip.
> 2. Go to your Xcode project’s “General” settings. Drag RealmSwift.framework and Realm.framework from the appropriate
>      Swift-versioned directory for your project in ios/, osx/, tvos/ or
>      watchos/ directory to the “Embedded Binaries” section. Make sure Copy
>      items if needed is selected (except if using Realm on multiple
>      platforms in your project) and click Finish.
> 3. In your unit test target’s “Build Settings”, add the parent path to RealmSwift.framework in the “Framework Search Paths” section.
> 4. If using Realm in an iOS, tvOS or watchOS project, create a new “Run Script Phase” in your app’s target’s “Build Phases” and paste the
>      following snippet in the script text field:
>
> `bash "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/Realm.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"`

I need to create a custom framework so that I can share multiple classes between apps. These classes use the Realm and RealmSwift Framework.

So I created a custom framework and added some classes. For these classes to work however, I need to have a link to the Realm framework within my custom framework.

I'm unsure how this can be done as in step 2, it states to drag the Realm and RealmSwift frameworks into the 'embedded section' of the project's general settings. But with a framework project, there is no embedded section. There is the 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' section. I dragged the realm and realmSwift frameworks in there instead. But the custom framework will not build and it says that no module could be found for RealmSwift.

I'm unsure in a framework project if the search paths are the same as what they would be with a regular xcode project ( i.e. $(PROJECT_DIR) ) and I'm unsure what level I should expect to see the Realm and RealmSwift frameworks in my project explorer.

Answer (score 1):

It's very annoying working with framework and library, if your framework is not packed into a `.framework`, then you might do something like this, might work:

1. Create a folder for your framework, add some source files
2. Add a `.podspec` with dependencies is Realm and RealmSwift, other value then you can learn from other pod
3. Create a normal app project
4. Install your framework into that app project with cocoapods with `:path` point to your folder, this will install realm and realmswift along with it
5. Now you can code your framework with realm normally without hard linking

For cocoapods and framework related stuff, check [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/126365/ios-frameworks-tutorial)

For framework project, what i usually do is avoid packing third party lib/framework into my .framework, i have 2 solution for this:

1. Let user does the job, mean you will create completion block and let them save it to realm themselve
2. Only include headers of the third party lib into your project and hope it will build without source files, this only works with simple third party project that have few headers, probably not Realm

Comment: so there's no way of doing it wihtout cocoapods? When you say if my framework is 'not packed into a .framework then do the following'. I created a cocoa touch framework project, so would that nor mean it is of type .framework?

Comment: Cocoapods is not an actual framework, its just a bunch of files, the framework making is handled automatically, framework project will build a .framework, they are indeed different, the framework is not meant to build on top of other framework, thats why it's very hard for native framework to handle that, check edit to see what i did for framework project

Comment: I used cocoapods to get the realm frameworks into my custom framework rather than the manual install. It is now building and I can use my custom framework in an xCode project. The xcode project has my custom framework installed and also the realm and realmswift framework installed. Does you see aany potential issues with that approach?

Comment: I'd recommend you to use CocoaPods for your main project as well. This will make everything even more simpler. The provided tutorial demonstrates how to achieve this.

Comment: @user2363025 not sure about this, you can try the package in an app and see if it works